# mongodb: drop all collections

Tags: mongodb

How to remove existing content before entering a replicaset the first time?

mongodb worries about:

> ... has data already, cannot initiate set.  All members except initiator must be empty.

Answer (score 4):

`db.dropDatabase()` will drop the database, which will also drop all of the collections within a database.

If you need to see what databases you have, you can do `show dbs`.

*Update*: Here's a script to **delete everything, make sure you really want to do this**:

```
var dbs = db.getSisterDB('admin').adminCommand("listDatabases").databases
for(d in dbs) db.getSisterDB(dbs[d].name).dropDatabase();
```

Comment: WARNING: This will drop the admin and local db's also

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the contents of the mongodb data directories.

On Unix-like operating systems, using the default apths:

```
systemctl stop mongod   # or the equivalent if not using something with systemd
rm -r /var/lib/mongodb/*  # Double check that this is not a box with data you want to keep (i.e a secondary, not the initiator
systemctl start mongod  # or the relevant one for your init system
```